# What is the reason for the instant loss of a vaccum through the sealed glass tube after shuting off a pump?

Tags: pumps, vacuum

A pump is connected to a glass tube to evacuate it. The reading shows 0.4 mbar when the pump is on because of a vacuum. As soon as the pump is turned off, the pressure in the tube becomes equal to atmospheric pressure.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that there is a safety valve in the pump which releases back pressure when the pump is not running.  Vacuum pumps aren't designed to hold a static pressure gradient when they aren't running, and I suspect trying to do so for long periods of time can damage the pump.

Comment: If Chris is correct, all you need to do to fix the problem is to include a valve between the tube and the pump, and shut off the valve before turning off the pump. I know this is standard practice when evacuating refrigerant lines for AC systems, which must be under vacuum before the system can be charged with refrigerant.

Comment: I'm closing this question as additional detail is required from the OP in order to provide a meaningful answer.